# Сохранить текстовый файл из 1С (НачатьПолучениеФайлаССервера)

Tags: 1с

```
    ФайлТХТ = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;
    ФайлТХТ.УстановитьТекст(Шифрованыйтекст);
    АдресВХ = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(ФайлТХТ);
    НачатьПолучениеФайлаССервера(АдресВХ);
```

Ошибка получения файлов
по причине:
Ошибка при выполнении файловой операции  '/e1cib/tempstorage/5160d717-ce6b-43a8-9b07-f1bf7b546b0c?seanceId=940e8d23-6daa-4e90-9d8e-a3fd177f6b57'. Значение данного типа невозможно преобразовать для передачи как файл. (ТекстовыйДокумент)

Цель сохранить ТекстовыйДокумент в виде .txt
Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2):

```
    ВременнойФайл = ПолучитьИмяВременногоФайла("txt");
    
    ФайлТХТ = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;
    ФайлТХТ.УстановитьТекст("Привет");
    ФайлТХТ.Записать(ВременнойФайл);
    
    ФайлДвоичныеДанные = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(ВременнойФайл);
    
    АдресВХ = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(ФайлДвоичныеДанные);
    
    НачатьПолучениеФайлаССервера(АдресВХ);
    
    Попытка
        УдалитьФайлы(ВременнойФайл);
    Исключение
    КонецПопытки;
```

Comment: А как быть если Использование синхронных методов на клиенте запрещено? Я как раз пытаюсь не использовать метод Записать. И в чем смысл получать ДД из врем.файла с компа если я с таким же успехом получаю ДД так: 
"ФайлТХТ = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;
  ФайлТХТ.УстановитьТекст(Шифрованыйтекст);
  АдресВХ = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(ФайлТХТ);"
В чём смысл?

Comment: @Cheid, посмотреть в синтакс-помощнике методы объекта "ТекстовыйДокумент". У него еще имеется метод "ЗаписатьАсинх()", только он доступен с версии платформы 8.3.18. Если версия платформы ниже, тогда пишите на сервере, а потом передавайте на клиента и сохраняйте. Посмотрите в отладке, что вы помещаете во временное хранилище - это не двоичные данные. Поэтому у вас и выдает ошибку.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Да версия платформы ниже, такого метода нет. Сделал через сервер, всё работает.

Comment: @Cheid, пожалуйста!